# Loading image in Java Code from C drive

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

i  am new to  Java . i was just trying to load  image as background in `JFrame`. What i wanted to do is get the image  from  C  Drive(that is not my workspace) so what i did  in `Board.java`:

```
   ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/image.png");
   img =i.getImage();
```

and did try to paint  it something  like this:

```
    public void paint(Graphics g )
    { 
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D  g2d= (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 100, null);
    }
```

And  then i am  calling in my main class like  this

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame(" Game") ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1200, 365);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new Board());

   }
```

but i am not getting any  image displayed , so is it legal way to  add `Image` ?

Comment: when you debug what is inside ImageIcon?

Comment: i have mentioned path to image.png, directly from   c drive ,  that is what i am trying to do  if possible .

Comment: If this is windows, shouldn't it be `ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:\1.png");`? (backslash instead of forwardslash)

Comment: @sampson-chen : in any case, it should be `"C:\\1.png"` . But that's not the problem, "C:/image.png" should work the same

Comment: i have tried both  , none of them  working  , i did code it as per a tutorial instructions and there is no error but problem with loading image  , when compile no image

Comment: Did you debug? If so , then what is inside `imageIcon`

Answer (score 4):

- Do not override `paint()` in `JFrame`
- Do not call `setSize()` on `JFrame` rather use `JFrame#pack()` before setting it visible
- Get into the habit of using */* as regardless of platform this is supported.

Here is an example I made:

[image]

- Create `JPanel`/`JLabel` instance
- Override `paintComponent(..)` in `JPanel`/`JLabel`
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to return dimensions/component which is correctly sized to `Image`
- Add `JPanel`/`Jlabel` to `JFrame` instance
- pack `JFrame` by `JFrame#pack()`
- set `JFrame` visible

**Test.java:**

```
//necessary imports
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    static String filename = "c:/test.jpg";//your file path and name here use / as it will work on linux platforms too so get into the habbit

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public Test() throws Exception {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize GUI and components (including ActionListeners etc)
     */
    private void initComponents() throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Image background = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        final Dimension jpanelDimensions = new Dimension(new ImageIcon(background).getIconWidth(), new ImageIcon(background).getIconHeight());

        frame.add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
                super.paintComponent(grphcs);
                grphcs.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
            }

            //return a JPanel that matches images size
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return jpanelDimensions;
            }
        });

        frame.setResizable(false);

        //pack frame (size JFrame to match preferred sizes of added components and set visible
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Create GUI and components on Event-Dispatch-Thread
         */
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //set nimbus look and feel
                    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    //create GUI instance
                    Test test = new Test();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice example. +1 for advices.

Answer (score 0):

use this format location instead

```
C:\\1.png
```

Comment: -1: NO! On windows only cmd.exe need \, the API works well with /

Comment: @abhishekkumar, \\ gets translated to \ due to escape sequences.

Comment: i changed it to  /  instead of \ and image loaded ,

Comment: Always use /, \\ is only needed by cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

With Swing you have to use paintComponent() in place of paint().

Comment: but there is not  any  image ,  can you please check the above mentioned code and  let me know the problem .

Comment: `JFrame` has no `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, which the OP can (and should) confirm using `@Override` notation.  This is one of the reasons why most people experienced with Swing will advise **not** to paint directly to a top-level container, but instead add a custom panel to it & take it from there.

Comment: Board.java doesn't inherit from JFrame. See frame.add( board )

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

Move `frame.add(new Board());` to before `frame.setVisible(true);`, i.e.:

Also, add `frame.pack();`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame= new JFrame("Game") ;
    frame.add(new Board());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1200, 365);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Once the JFrame is set to visible, only the event dispatch thread is supposed to touch it.

As a side note, override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()` unless you know exactly what you are doing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

The gist is that `paint()` is actually responsible for invoking the following: `paintComponent()`, `paintBorder()`, and `paintChildren()`. So if you just override `paint()` blindly, it will change the behavior of your component in ways you may not want.

Comment: Calling `setSize()` and `pack()` on the same `JFrame` instance really shouldn't be done. Also all Swing components should be created and changed in `Event Dispatch Thread` via `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX`