# Add an Background image to a Panel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a `JPanel`, and i want to add an image as its background. How can i do that ?

```
frame = new JFrame("Some frame");
panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
// NEED TO ADD AN IMAGE TO THIS PANEL

panel1.setLayout(cardlayout);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);

frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I need to add an image to the `panel` and how can i do it ?

UPDATE 1

```
    panel1 = new JPanel()
    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("1.jpg"), 0, 0, null);
    }
};
```

Comment: In the update I see you are forgetting to call `super.paintComponent(g);` in overridden `paintComponent` method, this could be a major problem (even the problem besides extracting image in `paintComponent`). overriden methods should optimally first call their `super`

Comment: see these answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237908/loading-image-in-java-code-from-c-drive/13238468#13238468) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660122/image-resizing-and-displaying-in-a-jpanel-or-a-jlabel-without-loss-of-quality/12660146#12660146) for some examples

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i tried adding `super.paintComponent(g);` but it still doesn't add an image to Jpanel

Comment: is 1.jpg located in the same directory as your jar? or is it bundled?

Comment: Yes, just below the file that contains the GUI. In the same package

Comment: if it is contained within the jar and the same package as the executing class try: 
                `Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("1.jpg"));` otherwise you'd have to do "/packagename/1.jpg" (note any period (`.`) within *packagename* must be replaced by /)

Comment: Do not try to load the image inside the `paintComponent(..)` method!  1) Load them when the component is constructed.  2) When drawing the image, use the image observer (the panel is an image observer).

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the method [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) of [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and use [`drawImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) on the [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object `g` as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026881/597657).

---

Also, check these two examples by [@trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod):

1. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/597657).
2. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/597657).

Comment: Also, I'd use `ImageIO` for the loading of the images

Comment: @sharonHwk `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("1.jpg")` may return a `null` result or empty image if the image you are trying to reference does not exist.  Make sure that the image exists and can be referenced from the context of your application

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"`createImage("1.jpg")` may return a `null` result"*  That is why I prefer `ImageIO.read(..)` - when broken it supplies much more useful information. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson No argument here

Answer (score 3):

You have a resource location problem.

`Toolkit#createImage` may return an empty image if the resource can not be found.

I suggest you use the [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) API instead, it supports a wider range of image formats, but will also throw an exception if the image is not found or can not be loaded.

How you load the image will also depend on where the image is.

If the image exists on the file system, you can simply use a `File` object reference, if the image is an embedded resource (within you application), you will need to use `Class#getResource` to obtain a `URL` to it.

[image]

```
public class TestGraphics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGraphics();
    }

    public TestGraphics() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new PaintTest());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintTest extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public PaintTest() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            try {
                // Use this if the image exists within the file system
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image/imageName.png"));
                // Use this if the image is an embedded resource
//                image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource/imageName.png"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension (image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - image.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight()- image.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: +1 nice advices and example. I always use `ImageIO#read` but never would have thought `Toolkit#createImage` would be any different, nice to know.