# How to set a background to JFrame by over-riding paintComponent?

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jframe

I just started Java GUI and I want to set a background image to JFrame by over-riding the paintComponent(Graphics g) method so that I will be able to add the child components over the image. I have looked at other answers but the code is too complicated for a beginner

Please use the following code to explain how this is done:

```
public class staffGUI extends JFrame {

public staffGUI(){
    super("Staff Management");

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
}       
}
```

Comment: *"I have looked at other answers but the code is too complicated for a beginner"*  Beginners should be consulting the [tutorial on custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for this task.  *"Please use the following code to explain how this is done:"*  So.. you want *us* to finish the task, and explain it to you in a way so simple that (even) you can understand it?  Voting to close - 'too broad'..

Comment: I know this question has been asked many times but every a user posts their own source code which make the code difficult to read

Comment: I already know how to do this using JLabel but then I cant place the child components over the image

Comment: I have also read many textbooks on Java GUI but none explains how to use this function specifically

Comment: Simply put, don't  use a `JPanel` as the primary surface.  Override it's `paintComponent` method and apply it as the frames content pane and then treat the frame as normal.  You will end up with a far more flexible solution. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791984/add-an-background-image-to-a-panel/13792503#13792503)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class staffGUI extends JFrame {

    public staffGUI(){
        super("Staff Management");

        this.setContentPane(new MyContentPane("C://somePath//image.jpg"));

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
    }

    private class MyContentPane extends JPanel
    {
         private BufferedImage image;

         public MyContentPane(String path){
               try{
                     image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
               }catch(IOException e){
                     e.printStackTrace();

                     image = new BufferedImage(100 , 100 , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                     Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
                     g.setColor(Color.blue);
                     g.fillRect(0 , 0 , 100 , 100);
                     g.dispose();
         }

         public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
              super.paintComponent(g);

              g.drawImage(image , 0 , 0 , getWidth() , getHeight() , null);
         }
    }
}
```

[Painting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) in the frame is always done on the content pane of the frame. The content pane is also where components are added. `MyContentPane` loads a `BufferedImage` from a given path. If loading fails, a blue rectangle is created as image. By setting the content pane in your example code to an instance of `MyContentPane`, you make `MyContentPane` render the complete inner area of the frame.

Comment: So where do I load the image?

Comment: oops, sry my mistake, i thought you just needed a backgroundcolor. one sec, i'll edit it to load an image

Comment: ok, i corrected my mistake, now it loads an image - atleast as soon as someone enters a valid path