# How to make a label background cover buttons in the style of a phone

Tags: java, swing

This is the format i am looking for.

[image]

I'm using windowsbuilder, so I would like to know how i can incorporate all this without errors.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791984/add-an-background-image-to-a-panel/13792503#13792503) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430)

Comment: Oh, and don't use WindowsBuilder, try setting it using appropriate layout managers by hand (There's at least two `BorderLayout`s and maybe a `GridLayout` depending on how you want it to work)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry I worded it wrong, how can I make the buttons appear behind it so when i press the picture the button gets pressed

Comment: You don't, you make the buttons transparent

Comment: On the bottom I see only 12 buttons. What label?