# Background image and JtextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to set a background image for my `JPannel` which contains many `JTextField` and `JButton` (I used `g.drawImage()`), but the the components won't appear unless the mouse passes by.
I can't make a `JPanel` for every component because I have too many of them.

Can anyone please help or point me into the right direction?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like either you've overridden `paint` or failed to call `super.paintComponent` when painting your image.

Make sure that:

1. You override `paintComponent` of your `JPanel`
2. You call `super.paintComponent` before you perform any custom painting

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791984/add-an-background-image-to-a-panel/13792503#13792503)

Also take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about painting in Swing

Comment: It appears "cannot find symbol" when i write super.paintComponent , I'm new actually to java ...

Comment: Then I "assume" that you're overriding `paint` of a `JFrame` or other top level container, which you shouldn't do. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Oh, and where are you "writing" `super.paintComponent`?

Comment: In the `override paintComponent` method.

Comment: Plus one to @MadProgrammer for attempting to answer this, and you for answering a question that was asked, but voted to close for 'lack of a runnable example' ..

Comment: Unless you can provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, I'm unsure how much more support I can provide, as it's all guess work based on assumptions

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm to bloody nice for my own good :P